# Making a responsive website and header image does not respond correctly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I set the image header width to 100% and when i check the max-width of 959px or lower[i set it to that] i notice the image does not respond and move along like it should. It actually gets even bigger than normal for some reason. My aside and section are working properly however.

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/u04xr6pd/2/

```
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/header.png" alt="taffies logo"></a>
    </header> <!-- end of header -->

</div>
```

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width:959px){
    .container{
        width:100%;
    }
    .sidebar{
        width:30%;
    }
    .first_article{
        width:50%;
    }
    header img{
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this code...

```
header img{
    width:calc(100% - 50px);
    margin:0 auto !important;
}
```

and apply that EXACT same width to this class `.first_article` to make it more responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You also have this code in your CSS:

```
header img {
    padding: 43px;
    margin-left: 260px;
}
```

So when your window width is less than `959px`, your image will have `width: 100%` but also the padding and margin, pushing it to the right. You need to add rules for padding and margin in your `@media` code as well. Something like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 959px) {
    header img {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 !important;
        margin: 0 !impotant;
    }
}
```

Adjust the numbers as needed.

The `!important` is there because you've defined the `@media` section first, which would then be overridden by the normal rules defined later. If you move the `@media` section below the normal rules, then you don't need `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

You have several misconceptions, but I can see you're trying and learning, so I want to give you some recognition on that. Now, for your problem, there are some thing to change, but the most important part: media queries goes AFTER the default definitions, not at the top, or you'll always have issues. So you need to change that, and then alter some things in your CSS, just not as many as when you started with this project a week ago or so. So take a look at [your forked and cleaned fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4dz3fkq/)

```
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
header, nav, section, article, aside, footer {
    display:block;
}
.container {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
body {
    background-color:#e8d4cb;
}
header img {
    padding:43px;
    margin-left:260px;
}
.first_article {
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    margin:25px;
}
.first_main_paragraph {
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#846a5f;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
.second_main_paragraph {
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#846a5f;
}
.first_article .contact_button {
    float:left;
    margin-top:165px;
}
.first_article .cupcake {
    float:left;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:19px;
}
.sidebar {
    float:left;
    margin:30px;
    margin-right:40px;
}
nav ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:myriad pro;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#3d2316;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:85px;
    padding-right:29px;
    padding-top:26px;
    padding-bottom:26px;
    width:39%;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
    color:#e8d5cc;
}
nav ul li {
    margin-bottom:3px;
    background-color: #CBAFA2;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #3D2316;
}
.company_info {
    background-color:#cbafa2;
    padding:20px;
    text-align:right;
    margin-bottom:100px;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#3d2316;
    font-family:myriad pro;
}
.about_section {
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    margin:25px;
}
.about_title {
    color:#3d2316;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:30px;
}
.about_text {
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#846a5f;
}
.orders_section {
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    margin:25px;
}
.orders_title {
    color:#3d2316;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:30px;
}
.second_order {
    margin-top:50px;
}
.order_text {
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#846a5f;
}
.order_numbers {
    color:#3D2316;
}
.gallery_section {
    float:left;
    width:600px;
    margin:25px;
}
.gallery_title {
    color:#3d2316;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:30px;
}
.contact_section {
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    margin:25px;
}
.contact_title {
    color:#3d2316;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:30px;
}
.contact_text {
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#846a5f;
}
footer {
    clear:both;
    font-family:arial;
    border-top:1px solid #aa8573;
    height:100px;
}
footer p {
    color:#784f3d;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:370px;
    margin-top:30px;
}
footer ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#784f3d;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    margin-top:30px;
}
footer ul li a:hover {
    color:#3d2316;
}
figure {
    float:left;
    margin:25px;
}
figcaption {
    text-align:center;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#846a5f;
    margin-top:15px;
}
span {
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    color:#846a5f;
    font-weight:bold;
}
@media screen and (max-width:959px) {
    .container {
        width:100%;
    }
    .sidebar {
        width:30%;
    }
    .first_article {
        width:50%;
    }
    header {
        text-align:center
    }
    header img {
        width:100%;
        max-width:462px;
        height:auto;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px auto;
    }
}
```

As you will notice, besides moving the media queries, I'm removing your margins and paddings for the image since you don't need them at all, centered everything inside the header and limiting the width of your image so it will be 100% UP to 462px which is the real size of your image. And that's it, your image now is perfectly centered and isn't out of control. And while you still have several issues in your page, you're really close (btw, it's a show of respect to vote up and accept answers since you're getting so much help here)